# Vertical align absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, css

I have two elements; input field and div - one next to another. Div is absolute positioned inside the relative element and positioned to the right of the input.

Input has fixed height, but div's height depends on the content.

What i would like to achieve is to middle vertical align div next to input. I am not sure if this is pure CSS possible, so thats why i added the javascript tag.

**HTML:**

```
<td>
<input type="text"/>
<div id="rel" style='position:relative;'>
<div id="content">
content
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {

position:absolute;
left:30px;

}

...
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly, so do you mean something like: http://jsfiddle.net/pt2BL/

Comment: What are your `div`'s doing inside a `table`?  If you want a pure CSS layout, you would not use a `table` except for displaying and tabulating data.

Comment: I agree the <td> tag is odd. Do you have the option of modifying your markup?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
td input {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Good you already have a table, [vertical centering via CSS](http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/) is not easy.

Btw: Instead of two divs and absolute positioning, you might use `margin-left: -30px;`